# Package compilation dynamic library loading error

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am wrapping a small c++ program in R by using Rcpp, and I checked beforehand that the c++ code is compiling directly with g++ 4.8.4 without warnings or errors. There are no external librairies, only STL is used.

When I compile my package in RStudio with devtools, I obtain the following error:

```
Updating PerseusR documentation
Loading PerseusR
Error in dyn.load(dllfile) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/leonid/Documents/Programmation/PerseusR project/PerseusR/src/PerseusR.so':
  /home/leonid/Documents/Programmation/PerseusR project/PerseusR/src/PerseusR.so: undefined symbol: _Z9lexicoPoslllRSt6vectorIlSaIlEE
Calls: suppressPackageStartupMessages ...  -> load_all -> load_dll -> library.dynam2 -> dyn.load
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

It seems that the compilation is fine and there is a problem with the loading of some dynamic libraries. 
In the undefined symbol, lexicoPos is the name of a function in the c++ code.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your home-grown attempt fails, I suggest you start with a created example:  Call `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` and compare all the files it creates with what you have.

Maybe you forgot the required line in `NAMESPACE`, maybe it is something -- we cannot tell from the information you supplied.

Comment: In RStudio, I used the option "create a package with Rcpp". The package works fine when I comment the function from the program, and use only a hello world example. The NAMESPACE looks like this (I can't format it correctly in the comment but there are three lines): exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")
importFrom(Rcpp, evalCpp)
useDynLib(PerseusR)